# WPF - Get DataTemplate without an event

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a WPF Data template defined in my Windows.Resources section.

I would like to access this (really a list box on it) via the code behind.  How can I do this?

I can't get what I want via an event because I want to get the reference in the completed step of a BackGroundWorker.  (Ie no sender (that is a UI element) to go off of there).

How can I get a reference to this?

I have tried:

```
myContainingPanel.Template.Find("lstBox", myContainingPanel);
```

and (Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx)):

```
ContentPresenter contentPresenter = myContainingPanel.FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>();
DataTemplate template = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
return (T) template.FindName(name, contentPresenter);
```

I would accept an answer that says I should use MVVM if there is an good example showing how that would work (with a backgroundworker completed event).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

[FrameworkElement.FindResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) should work. Finding data templates from viewmodel doesn't seem right to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is nice, but it just get the resource (all the stuff in it is empty).  I need actual filled template.