# WPF DataTemplate - x:Key vs DataType="{x:Type XXXX")

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate that I want to find using the `FrameworkElement.FindResource()`.  To do that I need to have a key on the data template.

The problem is that x:key and assigning a data type are mutually exclusive.  ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx))

So, once I set the DataType for my template, how do I find the Key value?  Is there some formula that converts the DataTemplate into a string for the Key?

(For inquries as to why I need to get the DataTemplate found by Resource see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951228/wpf-get-datatemplate-without-an-event).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The x:Key seems to be an object of type `System.Windows.DataTemplateKey`. So, you can "create" the key for your resource with `new DataTemplateKey(typeof(myType))`. `FindResource` will work with this key, since `TemplateKey.Equals` has been overridden.

Here is a very simple example application:

XAML:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Button Click="Button_Click">Test</Button>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```cs
//using ...

namespace WpfCsApplication1 {
    public partial class Window1 : Window {
        public Window1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var key = new System.Windows.DataTemplateKey(typeof(TextBlock));
            var r = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource(key);

            MessageBox.Show(r.ToString()); // to show that it worked
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great but is a C# solution.  Is there any way to do this from XAML directly?  For instance I have a DataType template that I'm using everywhere, but I also want to use it as a value in a TemplateSelector as well.  Same thing... if I add a key, I lose the data-type matching.  If I don't, I'm not sure how to ref it in XAML.

Comment: @MarqueIV: You should be able to reference it in XAML by using `{x:Type ...}` as the key.

Comment: Tried this... DataTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Type vm:IOPBase}}" but it doesn't work.  Crashes.  (FYI, I know the type is correct as the template has 'DataType="{x:Type vm:IOPBase}"' which works fine.)  Thoughts?

Comment: @MarqueIV: Good question, I thought it would work. Could you create a new question and post a minimal working example?

Comment: I had a feeling it wouldn't work, because even by your own example, the type isn't the key... a DataTemplateKey initialized with the data type is.  Yeah... I'll add a new one...